# convert total minutes to H:i:s time format in php

Tags: php

I have the total minutes like 7200 and I want that minutes like this 07:30:00.

Code:

```
$totalTime="720";
echo $totalTime*60;echo'<br>';
echo date("H:i:s",($totalTime*60));
```

Comment: How is 720 minutes equal to 07:30:00 ? I would say it's equal to 12:00:00.

Comment: `720` minutes or `7200` minutes? There's quite a difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$totalTime = "720";
echo date('h:i', mktime(0,$totalTime));
```

Comment: sorry 120 minutes or 7200 seconds and i want something like this   07:30:00.